# On "enter" make input element dissapear in the cell, but leave the text content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change cell content with javascript. 
When I click on a cell an `input` element appears that takes value of a cell's text.
After editing the text in input element when I click enter I want cell to be normal again (without having input element).

Here is a table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Content 1</td>
<td>Content 2</td>
<td>Content 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content 4</td>
<td>Content 5</td>
<td>Content 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is Javascript:

```
$("td").click(function(){
  if($(this).find("input").length==0){
    var cellContent = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append("<input type='text' size='"+cellContent.length+"' value='"+cellContent+"'>");
    $(this).find("input").focus();
}});// this part creates input element in a cell
```

Now problem comes after pressing enter when new content should stay in the cell but without input element.

```
$("td").click(function(){
  var newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
  console.log(newCellContent);
  $("input").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
      $(this).empty();
      $(this).html(newCellContent);
    }
    newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have to do

```
$(function(){

$("table td").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).find("input").length==0){
    var cellContent = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append("<input type='text' size='"+cellContent.length+"' value='"+cellContent+"'>");
    $(this).find("input").focus();
}

});
```

**NOTE:** How I am storing the `td Object` in a variable first before using it in the `keyup` function. Also you need to use `remove()` function to remove an element.

```
 var newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
        var tdObject = $(this);
```

====================================================================

```
    $('table td').on('keyup',function(){
  var newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
        var tdObject = $(this); //Storing the td object in a variable
  $("table td input").keyup(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log($(this).val());
      $(this).remove(); // remove() removes an html element in this case input elem
      tdObject.html(newCellContent);
    }
    newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
  });

    });

});
```

Check out the **[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/34p567uc/)**

Your References:

[jQuery DOCS remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: check out the fiddle link

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally suggest using CSS to show/hide the `<input>` elements, and using JavaScript to handle only the transfer of values and the blurring of the `<input>` on pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, like so:

```
// finding the <table> element containing the <input> elements,
// and adding an event-listener:
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  // 'e' is the event itself.

  // caching the element that triggered the keyup event:
  var current = e.target,

    // caching its tagName, in lower-case:
    tag = current.tagName.toLowerCase(),

      // we're using this check twice, so caching the result,
      // checking that the tag is equal to 'input', and that
      // the element has a 'type' property, and that the
      // current type is equal to 'text':
      isRelevantInput = tag === 'input' && current.type && current.type === 'text';

  // if the check returns true, and the key pressed (e.which) is
  // equal to 13 (the enter key):
  if (isRelevantInput && e.which === 13) {

    // we blur the element (allowing the CSS
    // to show the <label> text again, and hide
    // the <input>:
    current.blur();
  }

  // otherwise, if only the check itself is true
  // (note that the most difficult-to-satisfy condition
  // goes first):
  else if (isRelevantInput) {

    // we update the textContent of the <input> element's
    // next element-sibling (the <span> in this example)
    // to the current value of the <input> element:
    current.nextElementSibling.textContent = current.value;
  }
});

// Using Function.prototype.call() to use Array.prototype.forEach()
// to iterate over the NodeList returned from
// document.querySelectorAll():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table label > input'), function (input) {
  // the first argument of the anonymous function (here: 'input')
  // is the array-element of the array over which we're iterating.

  // setting the value of the <input> to the textContent of
  // of its next element-sibling (the <span> containing the
  // text of the parent <label> associated with the <input>:
  input.value = input.nextElementSibling.textContent;
});
```

The above JavaScript is coupled with this CSS:

```
td {
  height: 2em;
}
label > input {
  /* we're not using 'display: none' in
     order that the <input> elements can
     receive focus: */
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
/* once focused the <input>
   has a defined height and
   a visible opacity: */
label > input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 1.5em;
}
/* forcing the <span> to the
   next line of the <td>: */
label > input + span {
  display: block;
  height: 1.5em;
}
/* hiding the <span> when the
   <input> has focus: */
label > input:focus + span {
  display: none;
}
```

And with the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- wrapping the <input> in a <label> element
           means that clicking the <label> text will
           focus the <input>, using CSS to show the
           <input> and hide the <span>: -->
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 1</span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <!-- repeated content removed for brevity -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var current = e.target,
    tag = current.tagName.toLowerCase(),
      isRelevantInput = tag === 'input' && current.type && current.type === 'text';
  if (isRelevantInput && e.which === 13) {
    current.blur();
  }
  else if (isRelevantInput) {
    current.nextElementSibling.textContent = current.value;
  }
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table label > input'), function (input) {
  input.value = input.nextElementSibling.textContent;
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 2em;
}
label > input {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
label > input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 1.5em;
}
label > input + span {
  display: block;
  height: 1.5em;
}
label > input:focus + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 1</span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 2</span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 3</span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 4</span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 5</span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" /><span>Content 6</span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With your current HTML, however, and using jQuery I'd suggest:

```
// finding the relevant <td> elements,
// using on() to attach an anonymous
// click event-handler:
$('table td').on('click', function() {
  // creating an <input> element,
  // setting its 'type' and 'value'
  // properties:
  var input = $('<input />', {
    'type': 'text',
    'value': this.textContent

  // appending the created <input> to the <td> (this/$(this))
  // after emptying the <td> using empty(), and focusing the
  // created <input>:
  }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();

// binding an keyup event-handler using on(),
// passing the event ('e') to the function:
}).on('keyup', function(e) {

  // if it was the enter key that was pressed:
  if (e.which === 13) {

    // finding the <input> element with find(),
    // and caching the result:
    var input = $(this).find('input');

    // inserting the text string of the current
    // value of the <input> before the <input>,
    // and then removing the <input>:
    input.before(input.val()).remove();
  }
});
```

```js
$('table td').on('click', function() {
  var input = $('<input />', {
    'type': 'text',
    'value': this.textContent
  }).appendTo($(this).empty()).focus();
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    input.before(input.val()).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>
    <td>Content 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
  - [Child (`>`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).
  - [`:focus` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act).
- HTML:

  - [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).
  - [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
  - [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`eventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).
- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).
  - [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Always impressed by how much effort you put in your answers. Keep up the great work.

Comment: @blex: thank you very much! Obviously, if you feel like mentioning my awesome to your employers, should they need anyone... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$(this)` inside `$("input").keyup(function(event){}` will apply the functions (like `.empty()`) to the input.

You can work around this in several ways:

- Use `$(this).closest('td').empty()` instead: This looks for a parent 'td' to apply the functions to.
- Make a variable containing the `td` element, and use it to apply to function to.

Also: Setting the html using `.html()` will override the current content, so doing `.empty()` isn't necessary.

Example code (cleaned up a bit as well):

```js
jQuery().ready(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
    if($(this).find("input").length==0){
      var cellContent = $(this).html();
      $(this).empty();
      $(this).append("<input type='text' size='"+cellContent.length+"' value='"+cellContent+"'>");
      $(this).find("input").focus().keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which == 13){
          $(this).closest("td").html($(this).val());
        }
      });
  }});// this part creates input element in a cell
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Content 1</td>
<td>Content 2</td>
<td>Content 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Content 4</td>
<td>Content 5</td>
<td>Content 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your logic within the wrong scope which is in essence targeting the input. The following should now work.

```
$("td").click(function(){
  var newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
  console.log(newCellContent);    $("input").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
      $(this).parent().empty();
      $(this).parent().html(newCellContent);
    }
    newCellContent = $("input",this).val();
  });
});
```

Comment: when enter pressed that deletes input element but also the text inside input which should stay

Answer (score 1):

I would try to identify different tasks and assign them functions (`addInput()` adds an input, and `removeInputs()` removes any previously opened inputs). Try it:

```js
var shownInputs = [];

$("td").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).find("input").length) {
        removeInputs();
        addInput($(this));
    }
});

function addInput(el) {
    var cellContent = el.html();
    el.html("<input type='text' size='" + cellContent.length + "' value='" + cellContent + "'>");
    el.find("input").focus().keyup(function (e) {
        var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keycode == 13) {
            removeInputs();
        }
    });
    shownInputs.push(el);
}

function removeInputs() {
    $.each(shownInputs, function (i, el) {
        el.html(el.find("input").val());
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
        <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register the `keyup` handler inside your first cell `click` handler, just after the `input` was created:

```
$("td").click(function(){
  if($(this).find("input").length==0){
    var cellContent = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append("<input type='text' size='"+cellContent.length+"' value='"+cellContent+"'>");
    $(this).find("input").focus();
    // > Added
    $(this).find("input").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which == 13){
            var newCellContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().html(newCellContent);
            $(this).remove();         
        }
    }).focus();
    //
}});// this part creates input element in a cell
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e74jvvsy/)

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gr96qpuj/2/)- try it. Code below

You don't need multiple click binding

```
$("td").click(function () {

    if ($(this).find("input").length === 0) {
        var cellContent = $(this).html();
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).append("<input type='text' size='" + cellContent.length + "'     value='" + cellContent + "'>");
        $(this).find("input").focus();
    }
    currentTd = $(this);

    $("input").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $(this).remove();
            $(currentTd).html($(this).val());
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

because you're binding `keyup` event to dynamically created elements (`inputs`), you have to use `on` function on `body`

```
$("td").click(function(){
  if($(this).find("input").length==0){
    var cellContent = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append("<input type='text' size='"+cellContent.length+"' value='"+cellContent+"'>");
    $(this).find("input").focus();
}});// this part creates input element in a cell 

$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(event) { // code
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      $(this).parent( "td" ).html($(this).val());
    }    
});
```

and here is a working demo for you
https://jsfiddle.net/o2ka4qnb/